# Differentiation of Fourier Transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Suppose $X(jw)$ is the Fourier Transform of $x(t)$. We know that the Fourier Transform of $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$ is $jwX(jw)$. Now, why the following integration by parts does not give the same result?

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx(t)}{dt} e^{-jwt}dt = x(t)e^{-jwt}]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}jw x(t)e^{-jwt}dt =x(t)e^{-jwt}]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+ jwX(jw)$.

What to do with the first term $x(t)e^{-jwt}]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)dt$ exists.  Therefore $\lim{x\to \pm\infty}=0$, so the term you are worried about $=0$.

Comment: Do all integrable functions vanish at infinity, though? I know Dirichlet conditions hold here.

Comment: Integrability usually means $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}||x(t)|dt \lt \infty$, in which case the integrand $\to 0$.  This is presumably require if you want  to take the derivative of the Fourier transform.

Comment: It is possible that the limits at infinity are not $0$.  However in that case the limits do not exist.  For example the function could have a non-zero value on an unbounded set of measure zero .

Comment: In fact $\liminf$ of the integrand must go to 0 but not necessarily the $\limsup$ to be more precise with Steinberg statement.

Answer (score 0):

I like this derivation avoiding integration by parts step.

If $x(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{x}(w) e^{i\omega t} \,d\omega\right)$ than we can write $dx(t)/dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{x}(w) (i\omega) e^{i\omega t} \,d\omega\right)$. From last equation we can deduce $\hat{dx/dt} = \hat{x}(w) (i\omega)$.